# How to mock the method of a class under test with MOQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, nunit, moq

I have a service class that i want to unit test. The service calls a repository class method in order to save some data. But before I call the save method, I have a validate method that belongs to the service class under test which validates the properies of the class to be persisted as a parameter to the repository save method.

I know that to verify that the repository save method is called, i have to mock the repository class and set up the save method, but how do i verify that the validate method belonging to the service class under test is called when unit testing the method under test since they belong to the same class?

Answer (score 0):

You test this indirectly by passing in invalid data that makes the `Verify` method to report an error.

Examples:

- `Verify` throws an exception on an invalid value: Make your unit test check that this exception was thrown
- `Verify` returns `false` and the method under test doesn't call `Save` because of this: Assert on your repository mock that no call to `Save` happened.

Comment: So what you are saying is that i should ensure that the validate method throws up an exception by passing in invalid data through the unit test? Makes sense, i would just write a seperate unit test method to test that an exception is thrown up when i pass in invalid data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't untill you inject your service class in some other class. Here is what you need to do.

1. Create a class which takes an instance of your service class via public constructor or public property.
2. Mock the type of repository which your service class depends on, in order to save the entity and hold it in a variable.
3. Set up an expectation on the Save method of the mocked repo.
4. Mock your Service class but inject the mocked repo in your mocked service class (via property or constrctor).
5. Setup an expectation on the Validate method of the mocked service class.
6. Inject the mocked service class in the class created in step 1 and now the test would fail if your expectation werent met.